Apk has been signed with an insecure key size getting this error while uploading apk in private play
I'm getting the following error in Google Play:

Apk has been signed with an insecure key size getting this error while uploading apk in private play Store

For new applications it shows an error however for old application it is working properly - I don't want to create a new keystore.
![Apk has been signed with an insecure key size getting this error while uploading apk in private play Store]

Nowadays apps are usually uploaded as app bundle to Google Play, are you talking about old apps that still allow uploading of APK and where you don't use Play App-Signature (app signing by Google in their cloud)?

correct for public play store we are upload the bundle to google play store. but  i am trying to upload App on the private play store.

i have applied v2 and v3 signature while signing and it resolved that issue.
